# SQL IN operator not working when use other condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM schedule_backup WHERE shift_id IN (2, 7, 9) AND date BETWEEN '2013-05-22' AND '2013-05-22'
```

the above query not working, it show empty row selected

but the below is working

```
SELECT * FROM schedule_backup WHERE shift_id IN (2, 7, 9)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
BETWEEN '2013-05-22' AND '2013-05-22'
```

If you have a `datetime` column, this translates to

```
BETWEEN '2013-05-22 00:00:00' AND '2013-05-22 00:00:00'
```

I think you want

```
BETWEEN '2013-05-22' AND '2013-05-23'
```

...assuming that you actually have records with a date of `2013-05-22` and just want a single day.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I like to use the datediff function:

```
SELECT * FROM schedule_backup WHERE shift_id IN (2, 7, 9) AND
DATEDIFF(date,'1/1/2013') = 0
```

It's much more apperent as to what you're doing and you won't accidentally pull in another day or exclude a record at the very end of the day as the `between` operator will do.

Another alternative is to simply cast to date:

```
CAST(dateField AS date)
```

EDIT: Modified to MySQL syntax.

Comment: How does this help with MySQL?

Comment: I'm just blind and didn't see the tag. The principle is the same in MySQL. I've modified the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

`BETWEEN '2013-05-22' AND '2013-05-22'` - this is something like get numbers between 0 and 0. Change it to two different dates or two different times if it is the same day.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `BETWEEN 0 and 0` *per se*. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between .

Comment: @PM77-1 please read it as statement "get numbers between 0 and 0", not as an sql query.

Comment: My point is that SQL's `BETWEEN` is **inclusive on both ends**.  OP's problem is almost for sure with the `time` component of his date/time field and MySql's implicit casting.  In my personal opinion your answer is somewhat misleading.